# SOAP Request with <stdClass> tags

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, stdclass

This is my first time posting, so forgive me if I'm not very clear.  I will also preface this by saying that I really know very little about php and web services.

The issue I'm having is this:

A SOAP request is generated by an outside source (a client) and is then sent to my php SOAP server.  When the server receives the request, it is not correct at all.  A packet sniffer reveals that the request looks correct when it reaches the machine the php server is running on.  But, for some reason, as soon as the soap server gets the request, it is all messed up.

What is really odd is that only a week ago this code worked fine.  No changes have been made since then.  This has been tried on 3 different machines, one of which is running a different version of php (and is in a different state!).  One of the machines was turned off shortly after some successful testing, and then turned on today after this issue came up only to fail.

Here is a sample of the request sent by the client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <CoverageRequest xmlns="http://www.iicmva.com/CoverageVerification/">
            <RequestorInformation>
                <Organization>
                    <Name>NVDMV</Name>
                </Organization>
                <ReasonDetails>
                    <ReasonCode>BI</ReasonCode>
                    <TrackingNumber>NVDMV-2011-05-12 10:36:52:286678</TrackingNumber>
                </ReasonDetails>
            </RequestorInformation>
            <Detail>
                <PolicyInformation>
                    <OrganizationDetails>
                        <NAIC>26654</NAIC>
                    </OrganizationDetails>
                    <PolicyDetails>
                        <VerificationDate>2011-05 12T00:00:00</VerificationDate>
                        <UniqueKey>1234567890123456789</UniqueKey>
                        <PolicyState>NV</PolicyState>
                    </PolicyDetails>
                </PolicyInformation>
                <InsuredInformation>
                    <PrimaryNameInformation>
                        <ParsedName>
                            <GivenName>FIRSTNAME</GivenName>
                            <Surname>LASTNAME</Surname>
                        </ParsedName>
                        <Name>LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME</Name>
                        <DriversLicense>NOLICENSE</DriversLicense>
                        <FEIN>FEIN</FEIN>
                    </PrimaryNameInformation>
                    <Address>
                        <StreetAddress>12345</StreetAddress>
                    </Address>
                </InsuredInformation>
                <VehicleInformation>
                    <VehicleDetails>
                        <VIN>VIN1234567</VIN>
                        <Make>MAKE</Make>
                        <Model>MODEL</Model>
                        <Year>2000</Year>
                    </VehicleDetails>
                </VehicleInformation>
            </Detail>
        </CoverageRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is a sample of what the soap server gets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><CoverageRequest><stdClass>
    <Individual>
        <ParsedName>
            <Prefix />
            <GivenName />
            <MiddleName />
            <Surname />
            <Suffix />
        </ParsedName>
    </Individual>
    <Organization>
        <Name />
    </Organization>
    <ReasonDetails>
        <ReasonCode />
        <TrackingNumber />
    </ReasonDetails>
</stdClass></CoverageRequest>
```

Here is the code for the soap server:

```
<?php
    function CoverageRequest($pInput) {
    error_reporting(~E_ALL);

    require_once 'XML/Serializer.php';

    $options = array(
            XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_INDENT      => '    ',
            XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_LINEBREAKS  => "\n",
            XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_DEFAULT_TAG => 'unnamedItem',
            XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_TYPEHINTS   => false
    );

    $serializer = &new XML_Serializer($options);

    $result = $serializer->serialize($pInput);

    if( $result === true ) {
        $xml = $serializer->getSerializedData();
    }



    // Surround all of the XML in a single tag
    $xml = '<CoverageRequest>' . $xml;
    $xml = $xml . '</CoverageRequest>';



    // Insert the xml header at the beginning
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $xml;

    $fp = fopen('SOAPRequest.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $xml);
        fclose($fp);

    // Send the data to 4D's web service to be processed

        $client = new SoapClient('http://67.214.247.59:8090/4DWSDL/');
        $response = $client->VerifyInsurance($xml);

        $fp = fopen('SOAPResponse.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $response);
        fclose($fp);

    $xmlvar = new SoapVar($response, XSD_ANYXML);
    return $xmlvar;

    }

    // Clean up the response to match the guidelines
    function callback($buffer) {
    $buffer = str_replace('<ns1:CoverageRequestResponse>', '', $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace('</ns1:CoverageRequestResponse>', '', $buffer);

    $buffer = str_replace('SOAP-ENV', 'soap', $buffer);

    return $buffer;
    }

    // turn off the wsdl cache
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0');

    $server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => 'http://67.214.247.59/phpserver/verifyinsurance.wsdl'));

    $server->addFunction('CoverageRequest');

    ob_start('callback');

    $server->handle();
    ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Here is the wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:tns="http://www.iicmva.com/CoverageVerification/"
targetNamespace="http://www.iicmva.com/CoverageVerification/"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"

xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
>

  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.iicmva.com/CoverageVerification/">
      <s:element name="CoverageRequest">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestorInformation" type="tns:RequestorInformationModule" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Detail" type="tns:CoverageRequestDetail" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="RequestorInformationModule">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Individual" type="tns:IndividualBlock2" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Organization" type="tns:OrganizationBlock3" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ReasonDetails" type="tns:DocumentDetailBlock2" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="IndividualBlock2">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ParsedName" type="tns:IndividualNameComponent2" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="IndividualNameComponent2">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Prefix" type="tns:NameText2" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GivenName" type="tns:NameText4" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MiddleName" type="tns:NameText5" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Surname" type="tns:NameText6" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Suffix" type="tns:NameText2" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="NameText2">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:string" />
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="NameText4">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:string" />
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="NameText5">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:string" />
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="NameText6">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:string" />
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="OrganizationBlock3">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="tns:NameText1" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="NameText1">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:string" />
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="DocumentDetailBlock2">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ReasonCode" type="tns:ReasonCode1" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TrackingNumber" type="tns:ResourceIdentifier12" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ReasonCode1">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="NameText" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ResourceIdentifier12">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="CoverageRequestDetail">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PolicyInformation" type="tns:CoveragePolicyRequestModule" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InsuredInformation" type="tns:InsuredModule" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VehicleInformation" type="tns:RiskInformationModule" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="CoveragePolicyRequestModule">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OrganizationDetails" type="tns:OrganizationBlock4" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PolicyDetails" type="tns:DocumentDetailBlock3" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BodilyInjuryCoverage" type="tns:AmountBlock1" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PropertyDamageCoverage" type="tns:AmountBlock1" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="OrganizationBlock4">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NAIC" type="tns:PartyIdentifier18" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="PartyIdentifier18">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="DocumentDetailBlock3">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VerificationDate" type="tns:DateTime1" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UniqueKey" type="tns:ResourceIdentifier12" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PolicyState" type="tns:ResourceIdentifier14" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="DateTime1">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:dateTime">
            <s:attribute name="FormatText" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ResourceIdentifier14">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="AmountBlock1">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TypeofLimit" type="tns:ResourceCode9" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CoverageAmount" type="tns:Amount1" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ResourceCode9">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="NameText" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="Amount1">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:decimal">
            <s:attribute name="currencyidentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="CurrencyCodeListVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="CurrencyCodeList" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="InsuredModule">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PrimaryNameInformation" type="tns:IndividualBlock3" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="AdditionalNamesInformation" type="tns:IndividualBlock3" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Address" type="tns:AddresslBlock1" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="IndividualBlock3">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ParsedName" type="tns:IndividualNameComponent2" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="tns:NameText1" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SocialSecurityNumber" type="tns:PartyIdentifier9" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DriversLicense" type="tns:PartyIdentifier8" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FEIN" type="tns:PartyIdentifier8" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="PartyIdentifier9">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="PartyIdentifier8">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="AddresslBlock1">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="StreetAddress" type="tns:LocationText9" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SubsiteAddress" type="tns:SubsiteAddressComponent1" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="City" type="tns:LocationText1" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CountrySubdivision" type="tns:LocationCode2" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PostalCode" type="tns:LocationIdentifier1" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Country" type="tns:LocationCode3" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="LocationText9">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:string" />
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="SubsiteAddressComponent1">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Apartment" type="tns:LocationText2" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Building" type="tns:LocationText7" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Department" type="tns:LocationText7" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Floor" type="tns:LocationText2" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Room" type="tns:LocationText2" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Suite" type="tns:LocationText2" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="LocationText2">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:string" />
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="LocationText7">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:string" />
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="LocationText1">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:string" />
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="LocationCode2">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="NameText" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="LocationIdentifier1">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="LocationCode3">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="NameText" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="RiskInformationModule">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VehicleDetails" type="tns:ResourceIdentificationBlock1" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ResourceIdentificationBlock1">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VIN" type="tns:ResourceIdentifier11" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Make" type="tns:ResourceIdentifier12" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Model" type="tns:ResourceIdentifier12" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Year" type="tns:DateTimeText2" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ResourceIdentifier11">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="IdSchemeVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="DateTimeText2">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:string" />
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="CoverageResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Detail" type="tns:CoverageResponseDetail" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestorInformation" type="tns:RequestorInformationModule" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="CoverageResponseDetail">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PolicyInformation" type="tns:CoveragePolicyResponseModule" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InsuredInformation" type="tns:InsuredModule" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VehicleInformation" type="tns:RiskInformationModule" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="CoveragePolicyResponseModule">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CoverageStatus" type="tns:StatusInformationBlock4" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OrganizationDetails" type="tns:OrganizationBlock4" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PolicyDetails" type="tns:DocumentDetailBlock3" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BodilyInjuryCoverage" type="tns:AmountBlock1" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PropertyDamageCoverage" type="tns:AmountBlock1" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="StatusInformationBlock4">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ResponseDetails" type="tns:ParsedStatusComponent3" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ParsedStatusComponent3">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ResponseCode" type="tns:EventCode7" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="UnconfirmedReasonCode" type="tns:EventCode8" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="EventCode7">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="NameText" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="EventCode8">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:token">
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListAgencyNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListNameText" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListSchemeURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListURI" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="ListVersionIdentifier" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="NameText" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="VerifyInsuranceSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CoverageRequest" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="VerifyInsuranceSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CoverageResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="VerifyServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="CoverageRequest">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:VerifyInsuranceSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:VerifyInsuranceSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="VerifyServiceSoap" type="tns:VerifyServiceSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
    <wsdl:operation name="CoverageRequest">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:gnwSoap#CoverageRequest" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="gnwSoap">
    <documentation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
    <wsdl:port name="VerifyServiceSoap" binding="tns:VerifyServiceSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://67.214.247.59/phpserver/server.php" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Can anyone tell me why the response is missing the CoverageRequest section and why it is suddenly wrapped in stdClass tags?

Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to say. That method (serialize() isn't even documented.) Also, wondering why you are loading $pInput into a $result. If the SOAP envelope is already properly formatted, why not just pass it to 4D's web service?

Comment: Perhaps, you should write a real SOAP Server: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php and then take the input and write a SOAP client that you are sure conforms to the 4D Service.

Comment: You are sure that the client request is wat is send? You could try to check using wireshark to be sure. I agree with Bretticus with on the use of the SoapServer.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this issue?

Comment: A stdClass is a simple wrapper. You get a class of type stdClass when you a battlefield conversion of an array to an object, such as:

Answer (score 1):

I can't tel lyou abotu the response, but I can explain stdClass.

An object of type stdClass is a simple wrapper. You get a class of type stdClass when you a battlefield conversion of an array to an object, such as:

```
(object)array('keyname' => 'value')
```

If you did a var_dump() of this, you'd get:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["keyname"]=>
  string(5) "value"
}
```

All objects in every language inherit from some base object. I'm guessing that in PHP, it's stdClass.

(Vote me up if you like the answer.)

Dustin

Answer (score 0):

The CoverageRequest section is not part of the CoverageResponse class.  The CoverageResponse class contains a single instance of RequestorInformationModule and an open-ended array of CoverageResponseDetail objects.

My best guess for why stdClass is appearing is due to the use of unnamed complexTypes in the CoverageRequest and CoverageResponse elements.